# Jade разница между include и extends

Tags: jade

Подскажите какая между ними разница, возникло ощущение что инклудим мы статичные элементы, которые не меняются, а в блоках которые екстендим, используем изменяющийся контент используя block.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30641008/5951529

Answer (score 4):

Основное отличие между `includes` и `extends` в том, что первое дополняет контент, а второе меняет его.

`includes` используется для добавления содержимого одного `jade` файла в другой; по сути, это позволяет добавить кусок кода из одного файла в другой в указанное место.
Это удобно, например, когда надо дополнить содержимое какой-нибудь страницы новым контентом, в котором остальные страницы не нуждаются.

`extends` позволяет добавить контент и переопределить содержимое блоков, которые объявлены повторно.
Это удобно в том случае, когда для нескольких страниц надо вывести один и тот же блок, но с разным содержимым.